# Conditional formatting with R

Tags: r

I am trying to formulate a conditional expression a little bit complicated using two tables ("CS8_2007_2009_M&F.csv" and "CourbeDeCroissance_M&F.csv").

The first table contains around 60 000 individuals (nocs8) that have a value for weight (“weight”) and age (“agegestationnel”)

In the second table, I have for ages (“GA”) the corresponding 3rd, 5th and 10th percentiles of weight (respectively “3%”, “5%” and “10%”).

I’d like to code individuals (nocs8) depending on the age (“GA”) and the corresponding percentiles of weight (“3%”, ” 5%” and “10%”).

Here is my script:

```
mydata=fread("CS8_2007_2009_M&F.csv", 
             colClasses = c(rep("character", 5),
                            rep("numeric", 5 ),
                            "character",
                            rep("numeric", 7 ),
                            rep("character", 9), "numeric"))

setkey(mydata,nocs8)

weight=fread("CourbeDeCroissance_M&F.csv")
setkey(poids, GA)
```

normal weight

```
mydata[,quant:=0]
```

weight < 10%

```
mydata[, quant:=if(weight[GA==agegestationnel,`10%`]>mydata[[weight]]) 1, by = 1:nrow(mydata)]
```

weight < 5%

```
mydata[, quant:=if(weight[GA==agegestationnel,`5%`]>mydata[[weight]]) 1, by = 1:nrow(mydata)]
```

weight < 3%

```
mydata[, quant:=if(weight[GA==agegestationnel,`3%`]>mydata[[weight]]) 1, by = 1:nrow(mydata)]
```

And I got this message error:

```
« Error in weight["GA" == agegestationnel, "10%"] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
»
```

I'm wondering if it is due to the large size of my sample (nocs8=60 000) or the large number of conditions I’m asking (23GA X 3 percentiles = 46)? If so, What may I do?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

```
mydata <- read.csv("file1.csv", sep=";")
weight <- read.csv("file2.csv", sep=";")

data_merge <- merge(mydata, weight, by.x=14, by.y=1, all.x=TRUE)

data_merge$categ = NA
data_merge[!is.na(data_merge$weight) & !is.na(data_merge$X10.) & (data_merge$weight > data_merge$X10.), "categ"] = "Normal"
data_merge[!is.na(data_merge$weight) & !is.na(data_merge$X10.) & (data_merge$weight < data_merge$X10.), "categ"] = "low"
data_merge[!is.na(data_merge$poids) & !is.na(data_merge$X5.) & (data_merge$weight < data_merge$X5.), "categ"] = "very low"
data_merge[!is.na(data_merge$poids) & !is.na(data_merge$X3.) & (data_merge$weight < data_merge$X3.), "categ"] = "Extremely low"
```